# sql multiple join with OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables AA, BB and CC. BB and CC has one to one mapping to table AA ( with foreign key column : aa_id in both tables). Provided one condition that only either BB or CC can have reference to a row of table AA.

I would like to select **latest** 1000 rows from AA either joining with BB or CC. 
I could do separate queries to select 500 rows joining with BB and CC separately and make 1000. But this will not guarantee that I am getting latest 1000 rows from AA table.

So, I came up with following query to select record from AA by joining with BB and CC at same time. But due to **my restriction** ( only either BB or CC can have reference to a row of table AA), I am getting 0 rows from query below.

```
SELECT  * FROM AA 
       INNER JOIN BB  ON (
            AA.id = BB.aa_id
            AND SOME_CONDITION
        ) 
        INNER JOIN CC  ON (
            AA.id = CC.aa_id
            AND SOME_CONDITION
        )
ORDER BY
AA.id DESC limit 1000;
```

Could you please tell me how to do this? Is there any way so that I can OR these two JOIN conditions?

Comment: So what you want is all rows from AA which have a corresponding entry in either BB or CC? Are the actual values in BB and CC even important?

Comment: there are some differences. but the common thing is they both reference AA. I just wanted to select latest rows from AA which are referenced by BB and CC both. I can do `SELECT AA.ID FROM ...` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change your `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and you'll be fine. you may want to read [this article on codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for an explanation of different join-types.

your result should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM AA 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BB  ON (
    AA.id = BB.aa_id
    AND /* SOME_CONDITION */
  ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CC  ON (
    AA.id = CC.aa_id
    AND /* SOME_CONDITION */
  )
ORDER BY AA.id DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: But I'm afraid if I use LEFT OUTER JOIN, it will select records even if the condition "SOME_CONDITION" is not matched in both tables BB and CC.

Comment: if that can be the case, you can just add a `WHERE`-clause like `WHERE (BB.aa_id NOT NULL OR CC.aa_id NOT NULL)` to ensure one of them is always present.

Answer (score 1):

Since there will be only one match in `BB` or `CC` for each row in `AA`, you should replace your `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

So the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM AA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BB ON (
        AA.id = BB.aa_id
        AND SOME_CONDITION
    ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CC ON (
        AA.id = CC.aa_id
        AND SOME_CONDITION
    )
ORDER BY
AA.id DESC limit 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all records in AA where either a corresponding record in BB or in CC exists, you don't even have to join (assuming you don't need the values in BB and CC). Use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT *  FROM AA
    WHERE
    (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM BB WHERE AA.id = BB.aa_id
                /* AND SOME_CONDITION */
        ) OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM CC WHERE AA.id = CC.aa_id
                /* AND SOME_CONDITION */)
    )
    ORDER BY AA.id DESC limit 1000;
```

To me that looks cleaner (and it might also be a bit faster, since less data is handled, but I haven't tested that)!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: You said, 'the last 1000 rows of AA', so take care to specify AA.* in the select, or you will get 1000 rows made up of AA, then all fields of BB and all fields of CC (one of the two sets will be NULLed, too).

This gets the last 1000 rows of AA which match either BB or CC (or both):

```
SELECT  AA.* FROM AA
   LEFT JOIN BB  ON (
        AA.id = BB.aa_id
        AND SOME_CONDITION
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN CC  ON (
        AA.id = CC.aa_id
        AND SOME_CONDITION
    )
    WHERE (BB.aa_id IS NOT NULL OR CC.aa_id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY AA.id DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

@oezi is absolutely right.Few changes required in your query, Just remove `INNER JOIN`. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `AND` condition as @oeze mentioned.